# Form sempre visível

Tags: delphi

Bom pessoal, vim aqui porque já não sei mais o que fazer, testei de tudo....preciso deixar o meu FORM2 sempre visível (acima) de todos os programas abertos no windows. Meu programa fiz da seguinte forma:

Form1 tem um BUTTON quando eu clico nele executa o seguinte comando:

```
Form2.Show;
```

No ONSHOW do FORM2 coloquei o seguinte:

```
 SetWindowPos(Form2.handle, HWND_TOPMOST, Form2.Left, Form2.Top,Form2.Width, Form2.Height, 0);
```

E a propriedade FormStyle do Form2, alterei para fsStayOnTop. Mesmo assim, quando chamo o FORM2, não adianta, ele não fica sempre visível, se eu abrir o WORD por exemplo, ele já fica por trás. O que estou fazendo de errado ? alguma ideia ?

Comment: recomendo uma olhada nesta pergunta do SO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946150/how-to-bring-my-application-to-the-front), alguma das respostas de formas de fazer podem lhe atender. Mas 100% de funcionamento nenhuma delas garantiu.

Comment: Não sei no Delphi, mas no Lazarus, usei fsSystemStayOnTop no FormStyle, funcionou exatamente como precisava, inclusive obrigado pelas orientações pessoal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É [impossível fazer isso](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253). Não só no Delphi, mas em qualquer aplicação. [Imagine se duas aplicações fizessem isso](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413). Você teria duas janelas marcadas para estar sempre como sempre visível e aí como você decidiria qual vai mostrar?

Outras coisas são possíveis. Como por exemplo ficar por [cima da animação flip 3D do Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168833/how-make-a-form-always-on-top-even-if-the-windows-7-flip-3d-is-activated) ou ficar sempre por cima mesmo quando outras [janelas do seu software são abertas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727220/460775).

Answer (score 0):

Sei que é uma dúvida antiga mas vou deixar aqui mina contribuição.

Imaginamos que você tenha um form menu como form principal, se quiser que todos os forms abertos fiquem sempre na frente do form principal( menu ) basta colocar no create dos forms filhos o código abaixo e deixe o `FormStyle = Normal`

Adicionar no Create:

```
SetWindowPos(Self.handle, HWND_TOPMOST, Self.Left, Self.Top, Self.Width, Self.Height, 0);
```

Caso queira que o form fique na frente de tudo, inclusive de outros programas apena mude a propriedade do form para.

```
FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
```

Utilize `Form.ShowModal` ao invés de `Show` para que o mesmo fique sobre todos os outros do projeto, porém não terá acesso aos forms que ficarem atrás.

Answer (score -1):

Para que o formulário fique normal use a função ShowModal (Form2.ShowModal), desse modo você passa o controle para o form2.